Stopping time on the sum of a moving window
(Cross post from MSE)
Let $\xi_i$ be iid random variables, and define:
$$S_{(k)} = \sum_{i=1}^N \xi_{i+k}$$
Now, define:
$$\tau = \min \left\{ k : S_{(k)} \notin (a,b) \right\}$$
How can I find $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ or even $P(\tau < t)$, and whether there are any conditions under which these do not depend on the specific distribution of $\xi_i$ but on its first two moments?

To be more precise, I would expect to be able to express $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ in terms of $N$, the statistical properties of $S_{(0)}$ (for instance, in case we knew the initial state of the register and would be interested in larger values of $k$) and the moments of $\xi_i$. This is usually the case for problems in which one new iid is added to the sum when increasing $k$.
However, here $S_{(k)}$ acts as a shift register/buffer/sliding window/etc., where the oldest value is discarded every time a new one is added. Moreover, other techniques used in similar situations, like Wald's Identities, cannot be applied here, due to the sum taking place over a fixed number $N$ of iids.
Indeed, it turns out that one can prove that the following is a martingale:
$$M_n=S_n\left(\frac{N}{N-1} \right)^n - \mu \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{N}{N-1} \right)^i$$
but the exponential terms prevent us from using the OST since $M_n$ is not uniformly integrable.
Finally, I find it strange that there seems not to be a lot of research about the statistics of these moving windows/shift registers, but I am not able to find any bibliography on this type of problems.

Isn't $S_{(k)}$ just a random walk? Specifically, you have $S_{(k + 1)} - S_{(k)} = \xi_{k + N + 1} - \xi_{k}$? This should then let you use all the theory of random walks directly...

Yes but the fact that $\xi_k$ is correlated with $S_{(k)}$ makes most results not applicable

OK, one more stab - you can translate $S_{(k)}$ into an $N$-state Markov chain (continuous state, discrete time). There appears to be a strong theory on stopping times for Markov chains (that I admit to not really understanding), e.g.: https://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1256049786

@MartinModrák thank you for the recommendation. I already tried that approach and so far didn't get anywhere; the math becomes incredibly messy when you consider that the current state (S_{(k)}) does not only depend on the previous one but on the $N-1$ previous states (again, this is because you need to know $\xi_k$ to compute the transition probabilities to the next state)

This problem seems somehow easy when you state it and think about it, and due to how basic it sounds (it's just the statistics of a moving window) I would expect to find a lot of information or bibliography about it. But, to my surprise, it seems much more complicated once you start working on it, and I could not find any good reference describing it

You can translate to a multidimensional state that depends only on the previous time, i.e. $\bar{S}{(k)}$ r.v. over  $\mathbb{R}^N$ with the transition probability $P(\bar{S}{(k + 1)} = (a_1, ..., a_N) | \bar{S}{(k)} = (b_1, ..., b_N)) = P(\xi{k + N + 1} = a_1)$ when $a_2 = b_1, a_3 = b_2, ..., a_N = b_{N - 1}$ and 0 otherwise. Then - following the intro in Baxter & Chacon (link above) - you need to transform your stopping criterion into a "balayage" $\mu \to \nu$ and determine the potential operator $G$ for this process and you get your expected stopping time as $\int (\mu - \nu) dG$.

The details are a bit over my head, but the more I read it, the more it seems to me that your case satisfies the assumptions laid out (e.g. you have a transient process) and the balayage and potential operators for your process should be at least somewhat nice.

In what regime and with what precision do you want to know the answer?

@fedja I mean, as usually, the less constraints there are, the better. But I think working on the limit of large $N$ can help on giving some insight to the problem

And even larger $a<0$ and $b>0$?

I mean the explicit answer heavily depends on the step distribution an may be incomprehensible, but a decent asymptotic result or two-sided bounds may be not that hard, so I wonder how much you really want. Of course, "the more, the better", but what exactly will suffice for your purposes?

@fedja about large $a$ and $b$, not necesarily. For our specific research it would be more useful to have some results about $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ whose asymptotics hold in the regime $N \to \infty$ and $\sigma \to 0$ (for $\sigma$ the standard variation of $\xi_i$). Some strict bounds on the value of $\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ would as well be quite useful, specially if they sandwitched to the desired asymptotics.

I decided not to specify any of this in the OP question since I always imagined that it would be possible to find a more general solution, sinilar to the results obtained from random walk theory

similar to the results obtained from random walk theory The key difference is that your $N$ is fixed, so, if, say, all steps are bounded, it can easily happen that you never leave the interval with probability $1$, which is in the striking contrast with the random work where you are guaranteed to escape. So, the more specific you get about what your problem really is, the more hope you have for obtaining a meaningful answer at some point ;-)

@fedja could you provide an example of a case when one would not leave the interval with probability $1$? Intuitively to me, for decently large values of $N$, one can apply a central limit theorem-like argument to check that the pdf of $(S_{(k)} | \text{we didn't leave the interval for any previous } k)$ will be independent on $k$ and resemble a truncated gaussian, hence letting us to interpret this as a Bernoulli trial

Sure. Steps are uniform on $[-1,1]$, $a=-N-1, b=N+1$ (note that $N,a,b$ are fixed parameters in your setup!)
